# Convert pipe wrench to crescent wrench

Tags: tools

Has anyone seen any sort of jaw covers for a pipe wrench to be able to convert it to a crescent wrench (would also need to adjust the angle of the bottom jaw of course)?  It'd be nice to have able to use that for large heads without having to buy a larger crescent wrench or without marking up the head from the teeth by using it without covers.

Comment: Have not seen(or looked), but could probably make some with square tubing, cut in half.  Imagine this is for a once or twice a year job/s.

Comment: Yeah @crip659 for very occasional usage. Good idea on the square tubing as a starting point

Comment: It seams to me it would be more cost effective to just rent one!

Comment: What is this large bolt used on?

Comment: It was more of a just-in-case question @SteveWellens as I know in the past I've wished I had a larger crescent wrench. However, I have since ordered RIDGID 31400 which seemed like a better way to go and can open quite wide and have been happy with it. The largest nut of something I'm actively working on right now goes on a 1-1/4 bolt, and without measuring I'd guess it's around 1-3/4 which I've used that RIDGID wrench on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe wrench will never really act like a crescent wrench (or monkey wrench for that matter) because the jaw moves.  That's what makes it for pipes, the moveable jaw creates a lever that tightens on a pipe.  If you are solely looking to have something to put over the teeth to not mark up a piece then steel tubing would work.  But the moveable jaw means it will always be a poor tool for nuts/bolts, subject to more nut-rounding than the right tool, and having a second piece of metal between the jaw and the piece will only make this worse.

Comment: Ah good point about the moving. I guess you'd have to ensure it was in the moved state which would likely be annoying

Answer (score -1):

Building off the idea @crip659 had in the comment on the question, could cut square metal tubing in half and then line each with a decently thick layer of something like JB Weld's SteelStik epoxy putty. Then them onto the corresponding jaw to mold it to the teeth and remove to let harden.

This would also allow for compensating for the jaw angle and it would keep it from slipping when in use.  Can't speak to the safety aspect of this approach so use with caution.

Comment: this seems like just ruining a good pipe wrench

Comment: @TigerGuy the key piece is removing promptly before gardening so that it fits the teeth but nothing is on there permanently